# Groovy 2.4.7 and JDK 7

Tags: java, groovy

Is is safe to use Groovy 2.4.7 with Jdk 7 or are there any known compatibility issues ? I have been trying to search for this information but couldn't find anything substantial.

Thanks
Sashi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.

Groovy 2.4.x supports Java 6 and above.

Since Groovy 2.3, Java 8 is supported also (in case you want a version of Java that's not EOL)

See the table here: http://www.groovy-lang.org/download.html#requirements

```
Groovy          JVM Required (non-indy)    JVM Required (indy) *
2.5 - current   1.7+                       1.7+
2.3 - 2.4       1.6+                       1.7+
2.0 - 2.2       1.5+                       1.7+
1.6 - 1.8       1.5+                       N/A
1.0 - 1.5       1.4+                       N/A
```